# Access dom element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have created a simple tab system using ng-repeat the only problem is I can't access the dom element within the tab containers.

I have tried doing this:

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector('editor_'+UniqueId)).scope();
```

but that returns undefined in the console window.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brw7m8q5/4/

my code is pretty simple, i have got a watch function inside my main controller that checks for changes from my service, when a change occurs, it gets the data and generates a unique id and pushes the data to my main object which then create my tabs.

When the tab is created I wanna initialize a plugin on the div inside the tab container, but I can't access it don't know what am doing wrong.

Comment: In that case you need to have a directive... inside the directives link method you can initialize the plugin

Comment: Yeah got it working using a directive. Thanks

Comment: Raphael can you please share a fiddle or gist ? Would be very helpful for me.